# Manipulate checkbox prop in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to change a checkbox checked state when another is checked. It is working alright in my view but I can see in the chrome inspect tool that the `ng-reflect-model="true"` when it ought to not be. Here is my code sample

> component.html

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isCustomer" (change)="isCustomerChange()" [(ngModel)]="user.isCustomer" [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['isCustomer']" id="isCustomerId" class="accountType" name="accountType">
  <label for="isCustomer" class="checkboxLabel">
    <span></span>
     Customer Account
  </label>
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isStore" (change)="isStoreChange()" [(ngModel)]="user.isStore"[formControl]="registrationForm.controls['isStore']" id="isStoreId" class="accountType" name="accountType">
  <label for="isStore" class="checkboxLabel">
    <span></span>
    Store Account
  </label>
```

> component.ts

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  isStore: boolean = false;
  isCustomer: boolean = false;

  isCustomerChange() {
    this.isCustomer = !this.isCustomer;
    this.user['isCustomer'] = this.isCustomer;
    this.isStore = false;
  }

  isStoreChange() {
    this.isStore = !this.isStore;
    this.user['isStore'] = this.isStore;
    this.isCustomer = false;
  }
}
```

When store is clicked I expect customer to be unchecked (behaves so actually) and the customer checked state to be false (still true). How can I acheive this outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I need to make the change on the `ngModel` this way

```
isCustomerChange() {
  this.isCustomer = !this.isCustomer;
  this.user['isCustomer'] = this.isCustomer;
  this.user.isStore = false;
}

isStoreChange() {
  this.isStore = !this.isStore;
  this.user['isStore'] = this.isStore;
  this.user.isCustomer = false;
}
```